# Workflow doesnt sends Email for certain profiles

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow which sends Email based on certain criteria. When I create record as System Admin or some custom profile (Sales MX), I am getting emails correctly.

But this doesn't sends email for few profiles(Sales BR). But when I checked debug log, its showing Email alert was triggered correctly.

`11:44:46.84 (1084885799)|WF_ACTION| Email Alert: 4;
11:44:46.84 (1084918879)|WF_RULE_EVAL_END
11:44:46.84 (1085212088)|WF_ACTIONS_END| Email Alert: 4;`

Can anyone suggest what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

there could be a couple of reasons. 
First thing to check is de email delivarability option. Check Setup->Email->Deliverability if Access Level is set to "All email".
Second thing is to check, if the profiles have the "Send Email" user permission.
Third -sometimes weird- thing could be that you use an email relay. If you use that, for example Exchange could send the email. In many organisations users have a couple of email addresses. For example andreas.epping@xxx.com and a.epping@xxx.com. If the email address of the user record in Salesforce doesn't match the username of the email server, this might lead to problems.